# Calling Map from Firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

How can I retrieve data from `Map`. I am able to retrieve all the data in the `Document` but inside the `Map` I do not know how any idea?

**Update**
[image: firestore]

If I want to call out the `Lat` and `Lng` inside the `Map` how can I do it?

**Update**

```
The code that I am currently using
void _getPolyline(info, infoID) async{
      for (var i = 0; i < info.length; i++){
        final Map<String, dynamic> map = info.values.elementAt(i);

        var lat = map['Lat'];
        var lng = map['Lng'];

        PolylineResult result = await polylinePoints.getRouteBetweenCoordinates(
          googleAPiKey,
          PointLatLng(lat, lng),
          PointLatLng(lat, lng),
          travelMode: TravelMode.driving,
        );
        result.points.forEach((PointLatLng point){
          polylineCoordinates.add(LatLng(point.latitude, point.longitude));
        });
        _addPolyline();
      }
    }
```

**Update 2**
[image: error]

**Update 3**

`{0: {Lng: 101.14917509257793, BName: Mahsuri Bus Stop, Lat: 4.325185514680925}, 1: {Lng: 101.1338596791029, BName: Imperial Bus Stop, Lat: 4.3306596716452725}}`

This is the `print(info);`

Comment: I have not solved this issue yet. Please do feel free to leave a answer if you are able to solve it. Thank you and appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can already get all the data in the document, you just need to loop through each data and get the element in each of the `Map` items.

Here's a code sample:

```dart
 var snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('routes')
        .doc('Testing5')
        .get();

 var snapshotData = snapshot.data()!;

 for (var i = 0; i < snapshotData.length; i++) {
   final Map<String, dynamic> map = snapshotData.values.elementAt(i);

   var lat = map['Lat'];
   var lng = map['Lng'];

   print('Lat $lat');

   print('Lng $lng');
 }
```

Comment: It gives me this error `Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'num'`

Comment: Also, update your question with the code you tried.

Comment: I am able to print out the Data in the `LatLng` with the code you given `print ('Lat $lat')` but now I can't seems to put them in the `PointLatLng` I will update my question with the code that I am currently using.

Comment: should I save it in a List before using it?

Comment: When you say you can't put them in `PointLatLng` object, what do you mean? Do you get an error mesage? If you do please post it.

Comment: This is the error code. `Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'`

Comment: I am not sure how to check it. I will update my question with the screenshot really sorry that I am still a beginner does not have much experience. Thank you.

Comment: What is on line 109 of `StudentMap.dart`?

Comment: This is the code in 109 `final Map<String, dynamic> map = info.values.elementAt(i);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236237/discussion-between-victor-eronmosele-and-randomstudent).

Comment: I found out the reason. Your code works but does not show `Polyline` is because my API key does not have Direction API in it. Thats why it wont show up. Thankyou and sorry for the trouble.